# Wordpress not returning multiple post_type

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently trying to use `new WP_Query($args)` to retrive multiple post types on my wordpress, but it's only returning one post type.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('releases', 'post'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$asw_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

If I use `'post_type' => 'post'`  works perfectly, same as if I use `'post_type' => 'release'`, but both at the same time looks impossible. From my research, I know that's possible, but can't get it to work.

I'm currently using WordPress 5.4.1.

Comment: I have disabled Polylang to test, and yes, it was it!

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled Polylang to test, and yes, it was it!